# Hebrew/Aramaic names with Nekudot for Mishna Tractates

Tags: hebrew, mishna, vowels-nekudot

What are the names of the Mishna Tractates and Seders in Hebrew/Aramaic with Nekudot?

When I come across Tractate and Seder names (eg. מועד, גיטין, אבות, etc) they never have Nikkud. Are the names traditionally written without Nekudot? Even if so, what are the Nekudot as they have been handed down orally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%AA_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%AA) are the *mishnayos* (and their titles) with *nikud*, based on the [Kaufmann manuscript](http://kaufmann.mtak.hu/en/ms50/ms50-coll1.htm) from "late 11th - mid-12th c.".