# Online mishna with vowels (according to sephardic tradition)

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, mishna, vowels-nekudot

I would appreciate if anybody could help me in finding an online mishna vowelised in accordance with the sephardic tradition (i.e. following the Livorno prints opposed to the Vilna ones).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm not familiar with the edition you are seeking, so does [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/92109/3) help?

Comment: Not sure if this follows the Livorno prints, but here's the Mishnah online with nekudos: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%AA_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%AA

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions. If I understand correctly, the wikipedia page transcribes the Kaufman manuscript.

The text -- along side the nequdot -- are a little different than what I'm searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *mishnayot* on hebrewbooks.org vowelized and printed in Italy by a Sefaradi Menaked. I found three *sedarim* only:

[Seder Zerayim](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/43082) (Venezia)

[Seder Kodshim](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/40204) (Mantova)

[Seder Taharot](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/40203) (Mantova)

Comment: Hazaq u-barukh!